# Sets: Unions and Intersections.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets with $|A|=10$ and $|B|=7$. What can we say about $|A \cup B|$?
In particular, find two numbers $x$ and $y$ for which we can be sure that $x \le |A \cup B|\le y$ and then find specific sets $A$ and $B$ so that $|A \cup B| = x$ and another pair of sets so that $|A \cup B| = y$.

Finally, answer the same question about the intersection between $A$ and $B$.

I know that $|A \cup B|=|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$.
But I can't figure out what $x$ and $y$ values would work to make $x \le |A \cup B|\le y$ true.

I'm assuming |A U B| = 10+7-3, but also not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to look at the 'best' and 'worst' case scenario. We know that $|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|$ which implies $|A \cup B| \le |A|+|B|$

This is also the best upper bound we can get. Consider $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}, B=\{11,12,13,14,15,16,17\}$, then $A \cup B=\{1, \cdots, 17\}$ and $|A \cup B|=17=|A|+|B|$

Next we know that $A \subset (A \cup B)$ and $B \subset (A \cup B)$ so
$|A| \le |A \cup B|$ and $|B| \le |A \cup B|$. Since $|A|=10>7=|B|$ we get $|A \cup B|\ge 10$.

This is also the best lower bound, consider $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $ B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, then $A \cup B=A$.

Answer (score 0):

$|A U B|=|A|+| B|-|A \cap B|$ thus $‎10\leq |A U B|\leq 17$ if $B‎\subseteq‎‎‎‎‎{A}$ then $10=|A U B|$ and if $A$ and $B$ be disjoint sets $|A U B|= 17 $